# Apply `class` to a list column of a data table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider this data table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(A = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                 B = list(1, "x", "y"), 
                 key = "A")
str(DT)
## Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ A: chr  "a" "b" "c"
##  $ B:List of 3
##   ..$ : num 1
##   ..$ : chr "x"
##   ..$ : chr "y"
##  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "A"
##  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Can someone explain why the second action below always returns `numeric`? (I expected `numeric` `character` `character`).

```
DT[, `:=`(C=class(B))]
DT # ok 
##    A B    C
## 1: a 1 list
## 2: b x list
## 3: c y list
DT[, `:=`(C=class(B[[1]]))]
DT # why ??
##    A B       C
## 1: a 1 numeric
## 2: b x numeric
## 3: c y numeric
DT[, `:=`(C=sapply(B, class))]
DT # ok
##    A B         C
## 1: a 1   numeric
## 2: b x character
## 3: c y character
```

Comment: Try `DT[,  C := unlist(lapply(B, class))]`  The reason for 2nd case to have all numeric is because you are finding the class of the first list element which is `numeric` and assigning (`:=`) it to the whole column.  So, it is like assigning `1` as value to whole column ie. `DT[, D:= 1]`

Comment: @akrun Ok. Your solution is like my third one. Thanks for the explanation (you could post it as an answer).

Comment: Also `DT[, C:=class(B[[1]]), by=A]` works as expected here. I see.

Comment: Yes, it should work because we are grouping by 'A' and then 'B' will be a `list` of 'length' 1 or each 'A', but it might be slower

Comment: Crystal clear now. An ugly solution just to help the understanding: `DT[, C:=Vectorize(function(x) class(x[[1]]))(B)]`.

Comment: `Vectorize` is againg `looping` i.e. `lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1L], eval, parent.frame())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to get the same output as with `sapply`

```
DT[, C := unlist(lapply(B, class))]
```

The reason for second case to output all `numeric` class is because we are finding the `class` of the first `list` element which is `numeric` and assigning (:=) it to the whole column.

Comment: If sapply returns a matrix, then unlist-lapply will be returning a vector that is too long. If some rows have a class of length 2+, the OP should either not unlist or should wrap in toString, perhaps. I don't think unlist-lapply really adds anything vs sapply with some suitable function.

Comment: @Frank I think creating a huge matrix could impact the memory

Comment: I am not saying to create a huge matrix. In the only case where that might happen with `sapply` (where all rows have the same number of classes, `nc > 1`) `unlist-lapply` will be just as bad (since you'll be assigning nc*.N to .N rows. So, yes, unlist-lapply is a variant the OP had not listed, but that does not make it an improvement here. They could use plain old lapply (keep a list column) or sapply with toString (to collapse to a single string).

Comment: Ok, nonetheless, I am not your downvoter, but I don't think it's unreasonable. Your explanation (the final para) is good, but unlist-lapply is not a good recommendation, in my opinion, compared to what the OP already has with sapply. I'd rather see an answer that tries to find a good way to do something rather than just *another* way.